# Parameters for Move Base and Ackerman Vehicle simulated in Stage

Tags: navigation, simulation, sbpl-lattice-planner, stage, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are working with SBPL_Lattice_Planner with the Navigation Stack and Move Base to simulate an Ackerman Vehicle in Stage.  We have already modified the primitives to work with the vehicle as well as modified known settings.  We changed the "drive" type for the stage simulated vehicle to car as well.  When generating a path, we can see that a correct path with an expected Ackerman style setup is generated, however, the simulated car does not seem able to follow it.  Specifically, the simulated car does not seem to be making sharper turns that it should be capable of.

During the simulation, we review the /cmd_vel data being sent and it is rather small given the vehicles capabilities.  We even tested sending the data directly with a teleop program and the vehicles behaves as expected.  It would seem that the settings within move_base or the local planners are not functioning correctly.

In the params settings, we did attempt modifying the max velocity x and angular rotation variables to see if this would increase the vehicles capable turn radius, but had no luck.  We also made sure to set holonomic_robot to false.  Does anyone know of any other settings that may be modified or if there is an area in the code that should be modified as well?  Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99901/parameters-for-move-base-and-ackerman-vehicle-simulated-in-stage/) by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 213 on 2013-11-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you checked your STAGE velocity limits? I had serious problems until finding out [it was the culprit](http://answers.ros.org/question/66124/stage-velocity-limit/).

The ref page is [here](http://rtv.github.io/Stage/group__model__position.html).

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2013-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on 2013-11-12**:
Perfect.  Thanks.  Now just to figure out how to handle the rest of the Ackerman stuff needed.